# Where to find and install ASUS motherboard drivers for Linux

Tags: 12.04, drivers, asus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to download specific ubuntu drivers for my pc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197117/how-to-download-specific-ubuntu-drivers-for-my-pc)

This is my second day *ever* with Linux, and I had one heck of a time getting the nVidia drivers installed and working. Please, keep in mind I am *very* new and just starting out.

I currently have an ASUS P8Z68-V LE motherboard and I'm not sure if the drivers are installed. *Where would I go to find that out?* I am using Gnome as my UI. If I don't have the drivers installed, where would I go?

The ASUS site only gives me options to download for various Windows OS, DOS and "other" (in .ROM format).

Which should I take and how should I install? I'm mostly looking for audio drivers. A lot of music I play, either on YouTube or with VLC has a faint crackling in the background on Ubuntu, which gets much worse the higher I turn the volume up. *Could this be something other than the drivers?*

I doubt it's the hardware since the sound seems fine on Windows. I am currently running 12.04.

Comment: is there some piece of hardware in particular that isn't working?  If so, please update your question to reflect that.

Comment: @ImaginaryRobots I edited the question, hope it's a little more clear!

Answer (score 8):

There aren't generally any special motherboard chipset drivers that you need to install separately on Linux, like you need to do on Windows. The drivers are part of the Linux kernel. The hardware is detected at boot time and the correct drivers are loaded.

There are however cases where one might acquire hardware that is newer than the version of the kernel in the Linux distribution you choose to install; or even do not yet have any or full functionality in the upstream kernel.

In these cases though, you usually have to just wait or suffer, until the better drivers are available, as manufacturers typically don't offer additional drivers for Linux for these types of hardware. This is rarely an issue for motherboards though, as most of them use standard chipsets across the board, so are often covered by the drivers already available in the kernel.

The Ubuntu Kernel Team are also pretty good about ensuring that newer drivers are backported into the current development version of Ubuntu, to ensure a broader range of compatibility for users.

Comment: OK, I was looking for audio drivers though, since my audio quality is much better with Windows for some reason. A lot of music I play, either on YouTube or with VLC has a faint crackling in the background on Ubuntu, which gets much worse the higher I turn the volume. Could this be something other than the drivers? I doubt it's the hardware since the sound seems fine on Windows...

Comment: It could be the drivers, or any of the subsystems that the sound is going through before it gets to the card. It could also be the flash player (or browser), or vlc, or the audio/video files themselves. If you play the exact same file in VLC on both Ubuntu and Windows, does the issue still happen only on Ubuntu?

Comment: It happens with anything that plays sound, be it in Flash or VLC. If I play it in both, the issue is only un ubuntu.